# CSS aligning items to fit all screens

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've built this simple [javascript clock](https://codepen.io/samivino/pen/ewLEGQ)
But it's fit only for my screen. If i try it on a different screen, the clock hands are not in the right place. I know the problem is the `position: absolute` property, but what other way is there to correctly design this?

```
.clock {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15.5%;
  right: 44.8%;
  width: 135px;
  height: 135px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

Comment: you may have more success adding your image as a relatively positioned element inside your markup rather than as a background.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your Pen you can try this:

- Add `background-position: center top;` to html
- Add `justify-content: center;` to body
- Remove `right: 44.8%;` property on .clock
- Adjust `top: 15.5%;`  property on .clock so it can fit your clock image ( Make sure to use px instead of %)

Hope this helps. :)